# Dialog Show() Hide() and isShowing() methods functionality

Tags: android, dialog

I'm working on Dialogs in android and I found something strange in the implementation of Show and Hide methods.

Show updates the variable mIsShowing properly but Hide code doesn't have the statement to set mIsShowing to false!

I don't want to use Dismiss Dialog as in its OnStop I'm destroying the contents with in the dialog.

Can anyone guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hide() is implemented like this
By setting decoreview visibility gone

So you could check yourdialogue.getWindow().getDecoreView().getVisibility() == View.Gone
If its hidden or visible.
its a guess I am not sure if it will work